# ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]| [C]

Tags: c

I am trying to compile the following code on Ubuntu (64-bit), with Dev-C++ 5.9.2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// Afficher les nombres parfaits inférieurs ou égaux à un entier donné
void parfaitInf(int n)
{
    int i, j, somme;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        somme=1;
        for(j=2;j<=i/2;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0) somme+=j;
        }
        if(somme==i) printf("%d\n",i);
    }
}

// Tester si un entier est un nombre d'Armstong
void armstrong(int n)
{
    int somme=0,m=n;
    do
    {
        somme+=pow(m%10,3);
        m/=10;
    }
    while(m!=0);
    if(somme==n) printf("%d est Armstrong.\n",n);
    else printf("%d n\'est pas Armstrong !\n",n);
}

// Calculer la racine carrée d'un nombre entier
void racineCarree(int n)
{
    printf("La racine carr%ce de %d est %f",130,n,sqrt(n));
}

void menuPrincipale(int *choix)
{
    do
    {
    printf("\t\tMenu\n");
    printf("[1] Afficher les nombres parfaits inf%rieurs ou %cgaux %c un entier donn%ce\n",130,130,133,130);
    printf("[2] Tester si un entier est un nombre d\'Armstrong\n");
    printf("[3] Calculer la racine carr%ce d\'un nombre entier\n\n",130);
    printf("Votre choix ? ");
    scanf("%d",&choix);
    }
    while(&choix<1 || &choix>3);
}

int main()
{
    int n,choix;
    menuPrincipale(choix); //compilation error here
    printf("%d",&choix);
    // Not Continued
    return 0;
}
```

On line 51, my compiler gives me the error "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]".

On line 57, my compiler gives me the error "[Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]"

Why doesn't this work? I want to understand the current problem.

Comment: Why is this tagged `c` if you're using C++?

Comment: And which of the lines in the code you show are line number 51 and 57? Please mark them out with e.g. a comment.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up `int` and `int*`. In your `main`, `choix` is an `int` and `&choix` is an `int*`. In `menuPrincipale`, `choix` is an `int*` and `&choix` is an `int**` (pointer to pointer to int).

Comment: And the root of your problem is that you don't seem to be understanding pointers or the address-of operator `&`. Please find a good beginners book and read it.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C. (although that is also bad code in C, too, it is not illegal)

Comment: If I haven't overlooked something that code is valid C code (modulo bugs) (it even  includes the C versions of the standard library headers). So I'd say it is more useful to tell the OP that he accidentally compiled c code with a c++ compiler instead of accusing him of using the c tag for a c++ question.

Comment: @MikeMB I don't think anyone accused OP of doing that (but Olaf did switch the tags around).

Comment: @melpomene: *"accusing"* was probably too strong a term - sorry for that. But the OP's intention was clearly to write a c program, so the question really should have been: *"Why do you use a c++ compiler when you want to write a c program?"*. Not *"Why is this tagged c if you're using C++?"*. And yes, I often think that Olaf is too aggressive about removing c tags from any question that is somehow related to c++.

Comment: @HassanDhib: Just to avoid confusion: Although this may not give a compiler error when compiled with a c-compiler (I haven't checked) your code mixes up `&` and `*`  all over the place (or uses them where neither should be used) just as Kevin said in his comment and Jonathan in his answer. So you really should read a book or tutorial about how to use pointers in c (as arguments, parameters and variables).

Answer (score 0):

basic of pointers

```
int i = 1;
int *p = &i; // p is a memory address of where i is stored.  & is address of variable.

int j = *p; // j is the value pointed to by p.  * resolves the reference and returns the value to which the pointer addresses.

int **dp = &p;  // dp is the address of the pointer that itself is an address to a value.  dp->p->i

cout << i; // 1
cout << p; // 0x.... some random memory address
cout << j; // 1
cout << dp; // 0x... some random memory address that is where the p variable is stored
```

so as your your issue, as others said in menuPrincipale() your incorrectly using pointers.